# Dict comprehension to group words by first letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Does anyone know how to avoid the error `<generator object dictionary.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000001D295344580>`  that I get while trying to create a dict comprehension that generates specific keys: values?

For example, if we have a list:

```
words = ["hallo" , "hell", "hype", "empty", "full", "charge", "hey"]
```

I want to create a dictionary

```
{starting character of the item in list : list of items in words that start with the specific character}
```

so, for my example, the expected output would be:

```
{"h": ["hallo", "hell" , "hype", "hey"], "e" : ["empty"], "f": ["full"], "c": ["charge] }
```

My code:

```
{(chr(c) for c in range(ord("a"), ord("z")+1)):
            [word for word in words if word.startswith("a")]}
```

The same happens if i try to generalize the `word.startswith()` statement.

Comment: Can you please clarify your issue? Your code is not an [mcve], so we must rely on your information. A "<generator object dictionary.. at 0x000001D295344580>" is not an error, it is a generator object. Did you intend ``(chr(c) for c in range(ord("a"), ord("z")+1))`` to create a tuple?

Comment: They keys of the dictionary should be the letters a-z, and the values should be a sublist of words starting with the letter

Comment: are you probably looking for something like `{chr(c):[word for word in words if word.startswith(chr(c))] for c in range(ord("a"),ord("z"))}`?

Comment: This is the farthest you could get in a list comprehension. Then you could have another for-loop to drop off the empty values. But this is expensive. Use the normal for loop only once and you should arrive at the expected results.

Comment: yes thats what i was looking for, thanks a lot. i just cant rly follow how you got there

Comment: the last part can be changed to "for c in range(97,123)"

Comment: This looks like another phyrric victory for (in)comprehensions: just use a for loop because in (I guess) 99% of non-trivial cases it’s much simpler to write, simpler to debug, simpler to understand and change.

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution - and the corrected version - are rather inefficient, as they iterate on all letters, and for each letter, on all words, so 26*(number of words) loops.

You can do it by iterating only once on the list of words, by creating the dictionary key and the list that will contain the words on the fly. A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes this easy:

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ["hallo" , "hell", "hype", "empty", "full", "charge", "hey"]

out = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    out[word[0]].append(word)
    
print(out)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'h': ['hallo', 'hell', 'hype', 'hey'], 'e': ['empty'], 'f': ['full'], 'c': ['charge']})
```

with just 7 loops, instead of 26*7 and as many tests, and simpler code...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(words), lambda s: s[0])}
{'c': ['charge'], 'e': ['empty'], 'f': ['full'], 'h': ['hallo', 'hell', 'hey', 'hype']}
```

Once the words are sorted in ordinary lexicographic order, it's safe to group them by their first letters. (Sorting by first letter only would be sufficient as well.)

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, it's an object that you inserted as a key. It seems like you're confused about the syntax for dict comprehensions. The [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) you wrote (`(chr(c) for c in ...)`) doesn't expand, it gets used as the key instead. In fact, what you wrote isn't even a dict comprehension.

To do what you want, the loop needs to be **after** the key-value pair.

```
{chr(c): [word for word in words if word.startswith(chr(c))]
 for c in range(ord("a"), ord("z")+1)}
```

For comparison, here's a loose version of [the syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```
{key: value for x in iterable}
```

This is the naive solution. See [Thierry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242896/4518341) and [chepner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243012/4518341) answers for the better solutions. With the naive one, you'd also need to remove the empty lists:

```
>>> d = {chr(c): [word for word in words if word.startswith(chr(c))]
...      for c in range(ord("a"), ord("z")+1)}
>>> d
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': ['charge'], 'd': [], 'e': ['empty'], 'f': ['full'], 'g': [], 'h': ['hallo', 'hell', 'hype', 'hey'], 'i': [], 'j': [], 'k': [], 'l': [], 'm': [], 'n': [], 'o': [], 'p': [], 'q': [], 'r': [], 's': [], 't': [], 'u': [], 'v': [], 'w': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}
>>> {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
{'c': ['charge'], 'e': ['empty'], 'f': ['full'], 'h': ['hallo', 'hell', 'hype', 'hey']}
```